# Hiding your app from the task killer

Tags: android

I have read a lot on this subject and I am still in confusion. It would seem that the general answer is NO. But i have found an application that seems to "trick" the task killer. It is GO contacts EX. Even if it is running (it can be seen at settings->manage applications->running) and it can be force killed, it does not appear in the task killer. I think it is running because it is stared instantly as soon as you click it, and if it would be killed it would be impossible to populate the contact list so fast, and you would have to wait at least a few seconds.

I am trying to do the same thing if it is possible. I have an app that populates a list of contacts and other data but if the task killer kills it everything is lost. I have absolutely no problem with force stopping it or being killed by the system because it usually has time to save the data. I overridden the back button and it sends the app to the back stack and everything is OK, it starts instantly and doesn't keep the user waiting. But if a task killer kills it everything is lost.

GO Contacts EX does the same thing, with the exception that it can only be force stopped(and if you force stop it you have to wait a lot until the list is populated), and not killed by a task killer.

All help, suggestions (maybe I am not doing it the right way) are appreciated.

Comment: why would you want to? Even if you succeed, you'll be depending on behaviour which is likely to be fixed in later releases

Comment: Hm, true i have not thought at that. My wish would be to do this in a way that does not keep the user waiting. I saw that a lot of people use task killers and they might kill the app unintentionally, and after that they might send comments like: "It is a slow app, it's not good".

Comment: I am expecting that a user that force kills an application knows a little more that one that only set his task killer to auto-kill and would not be surprised if he has to wait a little at the beginning while the list is populated.

Comment: if you think your app is going to provide such a poor experience that people might want to kill it, I think you're focusing on the wrong problem!

Comment: Exactly the opposite. I am afraid people who wouldn't want to kill it might kill it by mistake and I already said I have no problem if someone force stops it(or installs it). Anyway I am testing with a rather large number of contacts but I hope people have less contacts :).

Answer (score 1):

This did work for me... I could practically kill any task. and yeah it works for go contacts  ex too http://thanthry.com/index.php/top-2-unique-task-manager-task-killer-apps/

Comment: Yes I have tried. It it can be force stopped of course. But it still seems to dodge the Task Manager's memory-clear. I have a problem with auto-kill not force stop... Thanks for the link too!